# Add UserControl in MainWindow from another UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I have two UserControls in UserControl_1 there is a button to add the UserControl_2 inside a StackPanel that is in MainWindow.axml. I'm doing the following in UserControl_1:

```
private void Button_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    UserControl_2 uc = new UserControl_2();

    ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).stackpanel_2.Children.Add(uc);
}
```

How can I do this within the MVVM pattern ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, you **don't** do this with MVVM.

In MVVM, your View is a visual representation of the data contained within the View Model. You would never directly add a control, because it wouldn't represent any data!

If you had an `ItemsControl` on your View that was bound to a collection in the View Model, then adding an item to that collection would add the appropriate controls. This is how you would do the spirit of what your existing code does in MVVM.